# The 'start_driver' method is coming back as undefined method `start_driver' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby, appium, appium-ios

This is the ruby file in my step_definitions:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'appium_lib'
require 'yaml'

desired_caps = {
    caps: {
        platformName:  'iOS',
        platformVersion: '11.4',
        deviceName:    'iPhone 7',
        app:           'PATH',
    },
    appium_lib: {
        sauce_username:   nil,
        sauce_access_key: nil,
        #wait: 100
    }
}

driver = Appium::Driver.new(desired_caps,)
$driver.start_driver

#login layout test

#finding the merrill logo
    def logo (driver)
        if driver.find_element(:name, "logo")
            return driver.find_element(:name,"logo")
        end
    end

    #finding the email textfield
    def email(driver)
        if driver.find_element(:xpath, '//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="DataSiteOne"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTextField')
            return driver.find_element(:xpath, '//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="DataSiteOne"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeTextField')
        end
    end

    #finding the password textfield
    def password(driver)
        if driver.find_element(:xpath, '//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="DataSiteOne"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField')
            return driver.find_element(:xpath, '//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="DataSiteOne"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeSecureTextField')
        end
    end

    #finding the email toggle
    def toggle(driver)
        if driver.find_element(:xpath, '//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="DataSiteOne"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeSwitch')
            return driver.find_element(:xpath, '//XCUIElementTypeApplication[@name="DataSiteOne"]/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeSwitch')
        end
    end

    #finding the remember me button
    def rememberMeButton(driver)
        if driver.find_element(:name, "Remember me")
            return driver.find_element(:name, "Remember me")
        end
    end

    #finding the login button
    def loginButton(driver)
        if driver.find_element(:name, "Login")
            return driver.find_element(:name, "Login")
        end
    end

    #finding Forgot Password button
    def forgotPasswordButton(driver)
        if driver.find_element(:name, "Forgot your password?")
            return driver.find_element(:name, "Forgot your password?")
        end
    end

Then(/^I verify the login screen layout$/) do
    $driver.start_driver

    logo(driver)
    email(driver)
    password(driver)
    toggle(driver)
    rememberMeButton(driver)
    loginButton(driver)
    forgotPasswordButton(driver)

end

$driver.driver_quit
```

This is the the Cucumber file

```
@LoginLayout
Feature: Test
    As an investment banker or analyst
    I want to be able to make a decision about a current acquisition or merger

@ValidLayout
Scenario: All elements exist on the page for the user
Then I verify the login screen layout
```

The purpose of this test is find that all the UI elements exists on the view controller, the ruby file runs but when I run it along with the cucumber it fails and its failing to recognize the star_driver method. I can't seem to figure out why it isn't recognizing that file.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have appium running, I thought I did but I didn't.